# How to remove phrase from beginning to end

Tags: java

I've been trying for a while now, and I just give up. I want to extract the data from type (regardless whether it's a capital letter or not) to the numbers. Pretty much, I'm trying to get rid of model and birthday in each line, but what makes it even more difficult, is that it's all one string. I spaced it out just to make it easier to read.

I'm trying to find the answer in REGEX java. This is what I was trying but, is deleting of course the whole String after the first number(4,66)

[;][mo].*

Thank you in advance!

Input:

```
Type:Carro;high:4,66;model:fourDoors;birthday:01/01/1980

type:Truck;high:5,66;model:twoDoors;birthday:29/05/1977

tYpe:motorcycle;high:1,55;model:fiveDoors;birthday:01/01/1980

type:Carro;high:4,66;type:model;birthday:6/12/1887

type:Carro;high:9,66;model:Doors;birthday:05/12/2010
```

Expected OutPut:

```
Type:Carro;high:4,66

type:Truck;high:5,66

tYpe:motorcycle;high:1,55

type:Carro;high:4,66 

type:Carro;high:9,66
```

Comment: Please, post the code you tried to achieve what you want!

Comment: this the regex I was trying to use but, of course is deleting whole string after

Comment: Are you sure that there are not Unix style line endings? Notepad under Windows won't see a line break there. That would ease things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will work for you. There are a few ways to make this code slightly smaller, however, this should at least help to get you on the right path.

I placed it into a main method, but it would be easy to put it into its own function. This would allow you to pass any number of arrays at it.

I added all of the logic in the comments within the code, I hope it helps:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*Get your strings into an Array*/
    String[] str = {"Type:Carro;high:4,66;model:fourDoors;birthday:01/01/1980",
                    "type:Truck;high:5,66;model:twoDoors;birthday:29/05/1977",
                    "tYpe:motorcycle;high:1,55;model:fiveDoors;birthday:01/01/1980",
                    "type:Carro;high:4,66;type:model;birthday:6/12/1887",
                    "type:Carro;high:9,66;model:Doors;birthday:05/12/2010",
                    "Expected OutPut:",
                    "Type:Carro;high:4,66",
                    "type:Truck;high:5,66",
                    "tYpe:motorcycle;high:1,55",
                    "type:Carro;high:4,66",
                    "type:Carro;high:9,66"
    };
    /*Create a "final staging" array*/
    String[] newStr = new String[str.length - 1];

    for (int j = 0; j < str.length - 1; j++) {//For each of your strings
        str[j] = str[j].toLowerCase();//set the string to lower

        /*If they don't contain a semi-colon and a model or birthday reference go to else*/
        if (str[j].contains(";") && str[j].contains("model") || str[j].contains("birthday")) {
            /*Otherwise, split the string by semi-colon*/
            String[] sParts = str[j].split(";");

            String newString = "";//the new string that will be created

            for (int i = 0; i < sParts.length - 1; i++) {//for each part of the sParts array

                if (sParts[i].contains("model") || sParts[i].contains("birthday")) {//if it contains what is not desired
                    //Do Nothing
                } else {
                    newString += sParts[i];//otherwise concatenate it to the newString
                }

                newStr[j] = newString;//add the string to the "final staging" array
            }
        } else {

            newStr[j] = str[j];//if it didn't have semi-colons and birthday or model, just add it to the "final staging" array

        }

    }

    for (String newS : newStr) {// finally if you want to see the "final staging" array data... output it.

        System.out.println(newS);

    }

}
```

> OUTPUT

```
type:carrohigh:4,66
type:truckhigh:5,66
type:motorcyclehigh:1,55
type:carrohigh:4,66
type:carrohigh:9,66
expected output:
type:carro;high:4,66
type:truck;high:5,66
type:motorcycle;high:1,55
type:carro;high:4,66
```

If I happened to miss something in the requirements, please let me know, I would be happy to fix it.

Comment: lol. It's working perfectly but, guess what? if I pass an array of for String[] myArr = {...}; it works, however if I convert an ArrayList to an array and pass it doesn't work, see it.  String[] myArr = myArrayList.stream().toArray(String[]::new);

Comment: It worked for me. We may have had differing results, because I defined "myArrayList" like this: List<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); If you are unable to do this, I can build you a script to cast your Objects to String.

Answer (score -1):

String str = "Type:Carro;high:4,66;model:fourDoors;birthday:01/01/1980,type:Truck;high:5,66;model:twoDoors;birthday:29/05/1977,tYpe:motorcycle;high:1,55;model:fiveDoors;birthday:01/01/1980,type:Carro;high:4,66;type:model;birthday:6/12/1887";

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");
while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tokens.nextToken() ;

    StringTokenizer tokens2 = new StringTokenizer(token, ":");
    while (tokens2.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String key = tokens2.nextToken() ;
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("type")){
            System.out.println("locate: "+key+"\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide some kind of documentation as to what you did, how you did it, and why it solves the problem at hand...